# How to get category name in opencart product search result page

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

My Controller  :

```
   <?php
class ControllerProductSearch extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('product/search');

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $search = $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $search = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $tag = $this->request->get['tag'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $tag = $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $tag = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
            $description = $this->request->get['description'];
        } else {
            $description = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
            $category_id = $this->request->get['category_id'];
        } else {
            $category_id = 0;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
            $sub_category = $this->request->get['sub_category'];
        } else {
            $sub_category = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.sort_order';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $order = $this->request->get['order'];
        } else {
            $order = 'ASC';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = $this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $limit = $this->request->get['limit'];
        } else {
            $limit = $this->config->get('config_product_limit');
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title') .  ' - ' . $this->request->get['search']);
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title') .  ' - ' . $this->language->get('heading_tag') . $this->request->get['tag']);
        } else {
            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        }

        // if (isset($this->request->get['name'])) {
            // $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        // }

        if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
            $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
            $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
            $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', $url)
        );

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title') .  ' - ' . $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        }

        $data['text_empty'] = $this->language->get('text_empty');
        $data['text_search'] = $this->language->get('text_search');
        $data['text_keyword'] = $this->language->get('text_keyword');
        $data['text_category'] = $this->language->get('text_category');
        $data['text_sub_category'] = $this->language->get('text_sub_category');
        $data['text_quantity'] = $this->language->get('text_quantity');
        $data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
        $data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model');
        $data['text_price'] = $this->language->get('text_price');
        $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');
        $data['text_points'] = $this->language->get('text_points');
        $data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));
        $data['text_sort'] = $this->language->get('text_sort');
        $data['text_tags'] = $this->language->get('text_tags');
        $data['text_limit'] = $this->language->get('text_limit');

        $data['entry_search'] = $this->language->get('entry_search');
        $data['entry_description'] = $this->language->get('entry_description');

        $data['button_search'] = $this->language->get('button_search');
        $data['button_cart'] = 'CUSTOMIZE';
        $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
        $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');
        $data['button_list'] = $this->language->get('button_list');
        $data['button_grid'] = $this->language->get('button_grid');

        $data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');

        **$this->load->model('catalog/category');

        // 3 Level Category Search
        $data['categories'] = array(); 

        $categories_1 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories_1 as $category_1) {
            $level_2_data = array();

            $categories_2 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_1['category_id']);

            foreach ($categories_2 as $category_2) {
                $level_3_data = array();

                $categories_3 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_2['category_id']);

                foreach ($categories_3 as $category_3) {
                    $level_3_data[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $category_3['category_id'],
                        'name'        => $category_3['name'],
                    );
                }

                $level_2_data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => $category_2['category_id'],
                    'name'        => $category_2['name'],
                    'children'    => $level_3_data
                );
            }

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'category_id' => $category_1['category_id'],
                'name'        => $category_1['name'],
                'children'    => $level_2_data
            );
        }**
// $this->load->model('catalog/category');

// $data['categories'] = array();

// $product_category = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);

// foreach ($product_category as $prodcat) {

// $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($prodcat['category_id']);

// if ($category_info) {

// $this->data['categories'][] = array(
// 'name' => $category_info['name'],
// 'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'])
// );
// }
// }
$category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);

        if ($category_info) {
            $this->document->setTitle($category_info['meta_title']);
            $this->document->setDescription($category_info['meta_description']);
            $this->document->setKeywords($category_info['meta_keyword']);
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path']), 'canonical');

            $data['heading_title'] = $category_info['name'];
        }
        $data['products'] = array();

        if (isset($this->request->get['search']) || isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_name'         => $search,
                'filter_tag'          => $tag,
                'filter_description'  => $description,
                'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
                'filter_sub_category' => $sub_category,
                //'name'              => $category_2['name'],
                'sort'                => $sort,
                'order'               => $order,
                'start'               => ($page - 1) * $limit,
                'limit'               => $limit
            );

            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($result['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_product_height'));
                } else {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('config_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_product_height'));
                }

                if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                if ((float)$result['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price']);
                } else {
                    $tax = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }
                    $cats = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_info['product_id']);

                    $sep = '';
                    $catnames = '';

                    foreach ($cats as $cat){

                        $catarr = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($cat['category_id']);

                        $catnames .= $sep.$catarr['name'];
                        $sep = ', ';
                    }

                    $data['products'][] = array(
                                        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                                        'thumb'       => $image,
                                        'name'        => $result['name'],
                                        //'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                                        'description' => html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
                                        'price'       => $price,
                                        'special'     => $special,
                                        'tax'         => $tax,
                                        'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                                        'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                                        'category'    => $catnames,
                                        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
                                    );

                // $data['products'][] = array(
                    // 'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    // 'thumb'       => $image,
                    // 'name'        => $result['name'],
                    // //'category'    => $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryName($result['product_id']),
                    // //'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    // 'description' => html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
                    // 'price'       => $price,
                    // 'special'     => $special,
                    // 'tax'         => $tax,
                    // 'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                    // 'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                    // 'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
                // );
            }
             $data['tags'] = array();

            if ($product_info['tag']) {
                $tags = explode(',', $product_info['tag']);

                foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                    $data['tags'][] = array(
                        'tag'  => trim($tag),
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', 'tag=' . trim($tag))
                    );
                }
            }
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter_tag'])) {         
            $filter_tag = $this->request->get['filter_tag'];      
            } 
            elseif (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {         
            $filter_tag = $this->request->get['filter_name'];      
            } else {         $filter_tag = '';      
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['sorts'] = array();

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
                'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_asc'),
                'value' => 'pd.name-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=pd.name&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_desc'),
                'value' => 'pd.name-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=pd.name&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.price-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.price&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_desc'),
                'value' => 'p.price-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.price&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $data['sorts'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_desc'),
                    'value' => 'rating-DESC',
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=rating&order=DESC' . $url)
                );

                $data['sorts'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_asc'),
                    'value' => 'rating-ASC',
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=rating&order=ASC' . $url)
                );
            }

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.model&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_desc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.model&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            $data['limits'] = array();

            $limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get('config_product_limit'), 25, 50, 75, 100));

            sort($limits);

            foreach($limits as $value) {
                $data['limits'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $value,
                    'value' => $value,
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&limit=' . $value)
                );
            }

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $pagination = new Pagination();
            $pagination->total = $product_total;
            $pagination->page = $page;
            $pagination->limit = $limit;
            $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&page={page}');

            $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

            $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));
        }

        $data['search'] = $search;
        $data['description'] = $description;
        $data['category_id'] = $category_id;
        $data['sub_category'] = $sub_category;

        $data['sort'] = $sort;
        $data['order'] = $order;
        $data['limit'] = $limit;

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/search.tpl')) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/search.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/search.tpl', $data));
        }
    }
}
```

My Tempalate file :

```
<!-- Products -->
                <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
            <?php $prod_anim=$config->get('glade_product_animation'); ?>
            <?php if (!isset($product['thumb_swap']) && $prod_anim!='overlay' || !isset($prod_anim)) { $prod_anim='static'; } ?>
            <div class="product-layout product-grid col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="product-thumb">
                    <?php if ($product['price'] && $product['special']) { ?>
                        <span class="onsale"><?php echo $language->get('text_onsale'); ?></span>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="image">
                    <div class="thumb">
                            <?php if ( $product['thumb'] && isset($product['thumb_swap']) && $prod_anim!='overlay' && $prod_anim!='static') { ?>
                            <div class="front-image">
                                <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"/></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="back-image">
                                <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb_swap']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"/></a>
                            </div>
                        <?php } else if ($product['thumb']) { ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a>
                          <span>Categories: </span><?php  echo $product['category']; ?>
                            <?php } ?>

                        </div>
```

I have mentioned my Controller and Template file , which i am using products search ... where when search i am getting product name , image , description as well ..
Now i want display the Category name also below the description for each product ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code

```
$data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    //'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    'description' => html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
                );
```

BY THIS CODE.

```
$cats = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_info['product_id']);

$sep = '';
$catnames = '';

foreach ($cats as $cat){

    $catarr = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($cat['category_id']);

    $catnames .= $sep.$catarr['name'];
    $sep = ', ';
}

$data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    //'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    'description' => html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                    'category'    => $catnames,
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
                );
```

And in the template file, You can simply call it in your loop using `$product['category']`.

Comment: I dont have model for this..can we directly call

Comment: @Krishna, Please check now.

Comment: Please check again and read my complete answer now. It will work.

Comment: What is the error you are facing? Did you tried to echo $product['category'] inside the view?

Comment: its not getting error but its not getting result also

Comment: you can see view file where i was inserted $product['category'] and updated my question view file as well

Comment: Are you echoing it inside your view? Under the description?

Comment: Yes you are correctly calling it in view. Please update your controller as well.

Comment: Update the controller over here too so that I can see.

Comment: Call this `<span>Categories: </span><?php  echo $product['category']; ?>` outside the loop

Comment: Updated Controller also where in controller we are calling categories as well by using that is there any chance to get category name

Comment: In the controller, replace `$cats = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_info['product_id']);` by `$cats = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($result['product_id']);`

Comment: Thanks bro it,s working...lets connect gtalk if possible for u